# setfocus() in form or items of j2me application

Tags: java-me

I had used the normal form in my project.
In that form i had used the item 
1)textfield
2)ChoiceGroup

I want to set focus on choice group when the from appears.How do i get this.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrentItem(choiceGroup);
```